# C++ Stack Using Templated Linked List - Memory Leaks

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to figure out how to remove all memory leaks from this code. I know this issue probably stems from the `push(T value)` function when using `new Node<T>(value)` but I don't know how to fix this.

```
#ifndef MYSTACK_H
#define MYSTACK_H 

#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;



template <class T> class MyStack{

template <class G> class Node{
  public:
  G value;
  Node* next;
  Node(T val, Node* n = NULL): value(val), next(n){};
};

public:
  MyStack(){
    head = NULL; 
    tail = NULL;
    my_size = 0;
  };

  ~MyStack(){
    delete head;
  }

  void push(T value){
    if(head == NULL){
      head = new Node<T>(value);
      tail = head;
      my_size++;
    }
    else{
      Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>(value);
      temp->next = head;
      head = temp;
      my_size++;      
    }
  }

// . . . (removed - brevity)

private:
  unsigned int my_size;
  Node<T> *head;
  Node<T> *tail;

};

#endif
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect elements in the stack other than `head` to be deleted?

Comment: Just FYI, `Node` does not need to be a template itself; it already has access to the `T` type since it is a nested type under `MyStack`.  That is, `MyStack<int>::Node` and `MyStack<float>::Node` would already be different types.  Making `Node` a template is redundant -- unless you need `G` to be a different type from `T`, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @SleuthEye Obviously with a destructor, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @cdhowie Oh, wow you're right. I didn't even realize that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete all the elements in your stack. Here are a couple of ways to do this:

1. In your destructor, loop through all elements in your stack and delete them.
2. In your destructor, repeatedly call `pop` until the stack is empty.

Option 2 is probably simpler to code, assuming that you already have a `pop` function, but potentially less efficient as it will be doing extra work to ensure the stack structure is maintained while it is being destroyed.

Comment: That seems so obvious now. I do have a pop function so I'll probably go with option 2 since I'm more worried about functionality right now. Thanks for helping!